# How to tell if an animation finished completely, or was interrupted?

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a UIView and two UISwipeGesture classes that animate the X rotation between 0 and -99, giving the flip board effect. If the user swipes down and then immediately swipes back up, the 'swipe down' animation is ended prematurely and it begings the swipe up animation.

How can I tell if it gets ended prematurely due to another animation being added? The animationDidStop:finished message gets sent, **but the finished value is always TRUE.**

Here's swipe down code:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

// This must be set before we calculate the transforms to give the 3D perspective (1.0 / -DISTANCE_FROM_CAMERA)
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -4000;
// Rotate on the X axis
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DegreesToRadians(-99), 1, 0, 0);

// Apply transform in an animation
CABasicAnimation* foldDownAnimatnion = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
foldDownAnimatnion.duration = 1;
foldDownAnimatnion.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
foldDownAnimatnion.removedOnCompletion = NO;
foldDownAnimatnion.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
foldDownAnimatnion.delegate = self;

// Identify this animation in delegate method
[foldDownAnimatnion setValue:@"foldDown" forKey:@"name"];
[foldDownAnimatnion setValue:theLayer forKey:@"layer"];


[theLayer addAnimation:foldDownAnimatnion forKey:nil];
```

And my delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)finished
{
    if([[animation valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"foldDown"])
    {
        // Why is this always YES??
        NSLog(@"Animation finished: %@", (finished)?@"Yes" : @"No");

    }
    else if([[animation valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"foldUp"])
    {
        NSLog(@"animationDidStop: foldUp");

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you when adding the new animation call `removeAnimationForKey:` with the old key. Do you still get `finished = YES`?

Comment: Yes, removing the animation causes the boolean to be set, finished = NO. This does have the side effect of resetting my layer back to its original position, but I think it must be the way to go. Will post back when I have found a solution to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add two BOOL instance variable(BOOL UpAnimationStarted; BOOL DownAnimationStarted;) In the beginning of SwipeUp set UpAnimationStarted to YES. And In the beginning of SwipeDown set DownAnimationStarted to YES. You can use these BOOL values to check animation interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidRönnqvist for pointing me in the right direction, I went back to my [O'Reilly book on iOS4](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=Programming%20iOS%204&btnG=) and redid the animation, the code now much cleaner:

Swipe Down:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

// This must be set before we calculate the transforms to give the 3D perspective (1.0 / -DISTANCE_FROM_CAMERA)
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -4000;
// Rotate on the X axis
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DegreesToRadians(-99), 1, 0, 0);

// Apply transform in an animation
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
theLayer.transform = transform;

CABasicAnimation* foldDownAnimatnion = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
foldDownAnimatnion.duration = 1;
foldDownAnimatnion.delegate = self;
[foldDownAnimatnion setValue:@"foldDown" forKey:@"name"];
[foldDownAnimatnion setValue:theLayer forKey:@"layer"];

[theLayer addAnimation:foldDownAnimatnion forKey:@"foldDown"];
```

Swipe Up

```
[theLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"foldDown"];

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
// This must be set before we calculate the transforms to give the 3D perspective (1.0 / -DISTANCE_FROM_CAMERA)
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -4000;
// Rotate on the X axis
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DegreesToRadians(0), 1, 0, 0);

// Apply transform in an animation
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
theLayer.transform = transform;

CABasicAnimation* animatnion = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animatnion.duration = 1;
animatnion.delegate = self;
[animatnion setValue:@"foldUp" forKey:@"name"];


[theLayer addAnimation:animatnion forKey:@"foldUp"];
```

The key really is that I am **applying the new transform to the layer, and then animating it**. What I was doing before was applying the animation to the layer and making it fill forwards, this caused problems when I removed it mid-way.